# How to write arara rules

Tags: arara

It seems the syntax for writing `arara` rules has changed since I last updated my copy of LaTeX.

On my old computer the following rule works as desired:

```
!config
# open rule for arara
# author: A.Ellett
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: open
name: PREVIEW
commands:
  - <arara>  @{isTrue ( isFile ("./.design/open.pdf.true"), 
                        "open -a /Applications/Skim.app ".concat(getBasename(file)).concat('".pdf"')
                        ""
                      )}
arguments: []
```

But on the new computer I get the follow error message:

```
I have spotted an error in rule "open" located at
"/Users/..../arara/rules/open.yaml". I could
not parse the rule, something bad happened. This part is quite
tricky, since it involves aspects of the underlying data
serialization format. I will do my best to help you in any way I
can. There are more details available on this exception:

DETAILS ---------------------------------------------------------
com.charleskorn.kaml.IncorrectTypeException at commands[0] on
line 8, column 5: Expected an object, but got a scalar value
```

I have no idea what this means.

I've tried going through the `arara` manual but I'm not finding anything useful.  The only thing I can find is that the mentioning of  `<arara>` is no longer supported.  But that leaves me clueless about how to rewrite this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has been announced for 2 years: The `<arara>` shorthand has been removed (cf. [the changelog](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)).

Comment: Oh and string returns have been removed in v5, you have to wrap them in `getCommand`.

Comment: And concerning rewriting I forgot to mention [the announcement post](https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/arara/news/release-v6/) of v6 which explained some changes and necessary actions. As I mentioned, you need to remove the shorthand and use `getCommand` as documented.

Comment: I plan to write an answer tomorrow, if it's okay. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, I won't be able to provide a crash course on how to write a proper rule because there would be lots of things to cover in a very constrained space. That said, I will try to comment things that have changed throughout versions based on your original rule and then provide some updates. `:)`

*(I took the liberty of removing comments so we can focus on the code itself)*

```yaml
!config
```

Correct, the first line must contain the object mapping metadata.

```yaml
identifier: ...
name: ...
```

Nothing changed here, so we are good to go.

```yaml
commands:
```

So far, so good, here we have the potential list of commands.

```yaml
  - <arara> @{ ...
```

This won't work anymore, for two reasons:

1. We moved from simple entries to actual structures (series 4). Each command (or subtask, as it's called in the documentation) is enclosed in a proper block. The only mandatory entry from this block is the actual command, denoted by the `command` key. So instead of:

   ```yaml
   - ...
   ```

   it should be:

   ```yaml
   - command: ...
   ```
2. The `<arara>` shorthand is no more (deprecated in series 5, removed in series 6). Instead, we encourage using the folding style of YAML (the documentation appendix covers this topic). So instead of:

   ```yaml
   - command: <arara> @{ ...
   ```

   it should be:

   ```yaml
   command: >
     @{ ...
   ```

Moving on...

```yaml
isFile(...)
```

This method is no more (maybe series 4.0, cannot remember). The reason for it is because we've replaced specific, hardcoded methods by `toFile(...)` which gives us an actual representation of a file.

```yaml
"open -a /Applications/Skim.app ..."
```

The tool does not allow commands in plain strings anymore. One of the reasons is that string manipulation for commands is tricky, unstable and error-prone. From series 4 on, we've introduced the concept of a `Command`, which allows you to build your commands in a safe way. So instead of:

```yaml
"open -a /Applications/Skim.app ..."
```

it should be:

```yaml
getCommand("open", "-a", "/Applications/Skim.app", ... )
```

Moving on.

```yaml
arguments: []
```

Correct, no arguments.

I will now present my proposal for an updated rule. I tried to follow the idea of the original rule with a couple of modifications. `:)`

```yaml
!config
identifier: open
name: Preview
```

Nothing new here. `:)`

```yaml
authors: []
```

This key is optional, but for the sake of completeness, I like to add it, even if it is empty. It helps me remind of the rule format.

```yaml
commands:
```

Nothing here as well.

```yaml
- name: Open Skim
```

Although it is optional, I find it useful to add a name to each task. Otherwise, the tool will use an unnamed reference which is not too easy to understand if you run into problems during your work flow. `:)`

```yaml
  command: >
    @{
```

Great, folded style. We are now ready to add our rule logic.

```yaml
        if (exists(toFile("./.design/open.pdf.true"))) {
```

Three things are happening here:

1. `.design/open.pdf.true` is converted from a plain string to an actual file reference (using `toFile(...)` method). A file reference can be created regardless of the file existence.
2. We use a method called `exists(...)` which, as the name implies, returns a logical value whether that file reference actually exists. Note that this method could be replaced by invoking the `exists()` method from the `File` class, so `toFile(...).exists()`  would be semantically equivalent.
3. We wrap the logical test in a conditional, so we can do certain things when the test holds true, and other things otherwise.

Moving on...

```yaml
            base = getBasename(reference.getName()) + ".pdf";
```

To ease reading, we created a local variable named `base` holding the base name (i.e, the file name without the extension) of the current file. Note that `file` is no more (version 6, I guess). We've replaced it by a way more powerful representation, which is the canonical, absolute reference to the current file (hence the `reference` name). For this specific purpose, it suffices to get just the file name, so we called `getName()` to get it.

```yaml
            return getCommand("open", "-a", "/Applications/Skim.app", base);
        }
```

We used a method called `getCommand(...)` to, as the action name implies, get a `Command` representation of what to execute. Each element to be provided (command + arguments) has to be explicitly parsed (in opposition to the plain string approach which was guesswork). Then we `return` the command we just created.

```yaml
        else {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Now we are in the `else` branch. Nothing should be done if that file does not exist. But nothing is, well, nothing, and we need to tell the tool that we want to run... nothing. `:)` If you do not return anything, `arara` will complain. One possible way to return nothing is to provide an empty list `[]`, so the tool understands it's an empty list of commands to execute.

```yaml
arguments: []
```

Nothing to do here, and we are done. `:)`

The complete `open.yaml` rule, for reference:

```yaml
!config
identifier: open
name: Preview
authors: []
commands:
- name: Open Skim
  command: >
    @{
        if (exists(toFile("./.design/open.pdf.true"))) {
            base = getBasename(reference.getName()) + ".pdf";
            return getCommand("open", "-a", "/Applications/Skim.app", base);
        }
        else {
            return [];
        }
    }
arguments: []
```

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: I'm away off the grid mostly and only on grid very briefly this afternoon.  I won't have a chance to play with this until the new year.  But, I did want to thank you for your very thorough answer.  There's more here than I think I even hoped for.  I just really didn't want you to think I was ignoring you in the interim.  See you in the New Year.

Comment: @A.Ellett no worries! I am very happy to help! Happy New Year! `:)`

Comment: Once again thank you.  This did the trick.  And you gave me enough here to work with to figure out how to fix up my other rules.  :-)